# Responsively fill initial screen with a div, then scroll as normal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a site with an initial 'landing page' look that you'd then scroll down from to see the rest of the content.

I can easily create a div that will fit the screen on the device I'm currently using, but how can I code for other devices of different screen sizes?

I've tried using '100%' which of course works initially but then continues to fill the screen when you scroll. I've tried defining a specific aspect ratio but again, that will only work for the screen I'm working on.

To be clear, I want the div, or img to fill the screen when a user first lands, then when the user scrolls the div/img should move up with the rest of the page.

I want to achieve this using only HTML or CSS.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do the trick:

```
.full-page-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

`vw` and `vh` units represent a percentage of the viewport size. Hence `100vh` will mean 100% of the viewport height and won't be affected by scrolling.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vw` and `vh` on the first `<div>` to fill the viewport. You can use this for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length